# How to do this integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$ where $x$, $y$ are constants.

Tags: integration

I want to do the integral below
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}},$$
where $x$, $y$ are constants. Do anybody know how to perform that?

Comment: I understand $\;x,y\;$ are *constants* here...or perhaps you took one part of a triple integral to ask about? Because cylindrical or even spherical coordinates would then seem to be useful...

Comment: @DonAntonio, Yes $x$, $y$ are constants.

Comment: Honestly, you should have done some google or bing searching first.  It took me about five seconds to find this: http://integral-table.com  Find number 41.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: Maybe the OP is interested in *how* to compute that integral, and less in its result?

Comment: @alex-m Even so, this is the kind of thing that is discussed in many standard text and reference works.  Should be pretty easy for a calculus student to find.

Comment: @bob.sacamento: Judging by the OP's SE profile, he seems to be a quantum physics student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \ \mathrm{Let} \ z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\tan t:\\
 \int \left ({x^2+y^2+z^2}  \right )^{-3/2}dz=\frac{1}{{x^2+y^2}}\int {\cos tdt}=\\
=\frac{\sin t}{x^2+y^2}+C=\frac{z}{\left (x^2+y^2  \right )\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}+C\\
→\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\left ({x^2+y^2+z^2}  \right )^{-3/2}dz}=\frac{2}{x^2+y^2} 
$$

Answer (score 2):

Try

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-3/2}=(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}\left(1+\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2\right)^{-3/2}$$

and now substitution

$$\sinh t:=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\implies\cosh t\,dt=\frac{dz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\implies$$

Another way with hyperbolic functions (larger...)

$$\frac2{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{dz}{\left(1+\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}=$$

$$=\frac2{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cosh t\,dt}{\cosh ^3t}=$$

$$\frac2{x^2+y^2}\int_0^\infty\frac{4e^{2t}\,dt}{\left(e^{2t}+1\right)^2}\stackrel{u:=e^{2t}}=\frac2{x^2+y^2}\int_1^\infty\frac{2\,dx}{(u+1)^2}=$$

$$\left.-\frac4{x^2+y^2}\frac1{1+t}\right|_1^\infty=\frac2{x^2+y^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x=y=0$, the you have to compute

$$\int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 1 {|z|^3} \ \Bbb d z$$

and this is clearly divergent. Therefore, let us assume that $x^2 + y^2 \ne 0$.

Perform first the change of variable $z = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} u$, in order to obtain

$$\int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}^3 \sqrt {1 + u^2}^3} \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} \ \Bbb d u = \frac 1 {x^2 + y^2} \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 + u^2}^3} \ \Bbb d u .$$

Forget for a moment about the fraction in front of the integral and perform the substitution $u = \sinh t$ in order to obtain

$$\int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt {1 + \sinh^2 t}^3} \cosh t \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 1 {\cosh^2 t} \ \Bbb d t = \int \limits _{-\infty} ^\infty \frac 4 {(\Bbb e ^t + \Bbb e ^{-t})^2} \ \Bbb d t$$

because $\cosh^2 t = \sinh^2 t + 1$ and $\cosh t = \frac {\Bbb e ^t + \Bbb e ^{-t}} 2$. Make the substitution $\Bbb e ^t = s$ and get

$$\int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac 4 {(s + \frac 1 s)^2} \frac 1 s \ \Bbb d s = \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {4s} {(s^2+1)^2} \ \Bbb d s = \int \limits _0 ^\infty \frac {(s^2+1)'} {(s^2+1)^2} \ \Bbb d s = - \frac 2 {s^2 + 1} \Bigg| _0 ^\infty = 2 .$$

Putting that fraction back you get the final result:

$$\frac 2 {x^2+y^2} .$$